# Can't extract this function from an expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to parameterize an Entity Framework query (EntityFrameworkCore 1.1.1) but I'm getting an error when extracting a function from an "Where" Expression:

> System.NotSupportedException :
>
> Could not parse expression 'school.Programs.Any(__p_0)': The given arguments did not match the expected arguments: Object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.TypedParameterExpression' cannot be converted to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression'.

I get that error when I try call `SearchSchools()`:

```cs
public IQueryable<SchoolResult> SearchSchoolQueryable(
    Expression<Func<School, bool>> schoolExpression)
{
    return _dbContext.School
        .Where(schoolExpression)
        .Select(s => new SchoolResult
            {
                Id = s.Id,
                Name = s.Name
            }
         );
}

// hardcoded test: doesn't work
public async Task<IEnumerable<SchoolResult>> SearchSchools()
{
    Func<Program, bool> p = program => program.Name.StartsWith("U");
    Expression<Func<School, bool>> expr = school => school.Active 
        && school.Programs.Any(p);
    return await SearchSchoolQueryable(expr)
        .ToListAsync()
}
```

However, it works fine when I rewrite SearchSchools so that the `Func` is inlined:

```cs
// hardcoded test: works ok
public async Task<IEnumerable<SchoolResult>> SearchSchools()
{
    Expression<Func<School, bool>> expr = school => school.Active 
         && school.Programs.Any(program => program.Name.StartsWith("U"));
    return await SearchSchoolQueryable(expr)
          .ToListAsync()
}
```

This seems kind of weird---I thought they should act the same.  Any why this might be occurring?

Comment: They are not the same. The problem and possible solution are explained in [LINQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) page.

Comment: @IvanStoev I am familiar with LINQKit but I suspect there may be another problem here.  I tried adding `.AsExpandable()` to .School but I still get an identical error.

Comment: It's not enough. If you are using LINQKit, change the type of the `p` variable to `Expression<Func<Program, bool>>`, then use `school.Programs.Any(sp => p.Invoke(sp))` and finally `SearchSchoolQueryable(expr.Expand())`

Comment: @IvanStoev thanks—your suggestion worked for me, but I am still confused about why one of my two solutions works.

Comment: Because when the `Func<..>` call is embedded in another expression, it's not really a `Func<..>` and the expression tree "see" the code inside. While when it's from external variable, it could virtually be anything.

Comment: For EF its a bug. EF parametrized the closure func and made tree in the form which throws parsing error in ReLinq. Tracking issue: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/8019

Comment: @Smit It's not a bug; there's no possible way for the first snippet to possibly work.  The information that EF would need in order to generate the query isn't available to it.  It can't translate arbitrary .NET code into SQL; it needs all of the necessary information to be in an `Expression`.

Comment: @Servy He probably has in mind that EF Core "by design" should be able to evaluate it in memory. Which IMO is no better than throwing exception :) The real bug for me is that in EF6 one can use `AsQueryable` and pass external `Expression<Func<...>>` variable, and EF was happy to process it, while now EF Core throws not supported exception as well.

Comment: @IvanStoev Just silently materializing the entire query into memory instead of doing the work in the DB would be a bug; it's a *huge* problem and results in people having code that doesn't work but without knowing that it doesn't work.  In this case there *isn't* and external `Expression<Func<...>>`, there's a `Func<...>`, so no, it can't "just process it".

Comment: @Servy Totally agree! But they did it (there is an option to prevent that behavior, but it's turned off by default), so I guess they consider it a feature, not bug.

Comment: It is a bug because EF throws exception. It is true that EF cannot translate the first snippet to server because its a `Func` instead of `Expression` but EF still should be able to evaluate it in memory. EF not doing it is the bug. Due to mixed sever/client evaluation mode, ideally if you can write a valid query in C#, it should generate results. If EF throws exception then its a bug. Brief details of client eval been summarized by @IvanStoev well.

Comment: For `AsQueryable` not working tracking issue https://www.re-motion.org/jira/projects/RMLNQ/issues/RMLNQ-28

Answer (score 1):

The error in the first case is that you declared `p` as a `Func<Program, bool>`.

It must be an `Expression<Func<Program, bool>>` for Entity Framework to understand the expression tree.

Comment: because when inlined it can still be treated as an `Expression`

Comment: But `school.Programs.Any()` doesn't accept an `Expression<Func<Program, bool>>`.

Comment: That's because not all implementations of `Any` need Expression tree information. For example, LINQ to Objects does not need it, but Entity Framework does.

Comment: Sorry that I seem to be missing something critical here, but when I look at it from the outside it seems to be violating referential transparency---when I pass the function as a value it works but not as a reference.   I would assume that there must be an implicit transformation or cast going on, but I don't understand the mechanism.  (I understand that EF uses Expressions to generate SQL, though.)

Comment: [Any() does directly support Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534338(v=vs.110).aspx).  You simply need to makes sure you have a using statement `using System.Linq`.

Comment: @mikebridge if you need further clarification we can discuss it in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139271/ef-question-43057695)

Comment: @ErikPhilips If the OP didn't have a `using` for LINQ then the code wouldn't even compile, rather than compiling and not running.  The problem is that `school.Programs` is an `IEnumerable`, not an `IQueryable`, so `Queryable.Any` can't be called on it.

Answer (score 1):

Your second example works because you have an `Expression` that represents the creation of the `Func<Program, bool>`.  You need to *have* a `Func<Program, bool>` because that's what `Any` expects, but all of the details of that `Func` need to be in an `Expression` so that the query provider can see all of that information and handle it.

In your first example the `Func<Program, bool>` is created in code, not in an `Expression`, so it's just regular old compiled code, and the query provider doesn't have enough information to translate some arbitrary .NET code into SQL, so all it can do is throw its hands up.

Comment: Based on your answer It sounds like I have a gap in my understanding of C#.  Based on my revised understanding, the second solution I had is a [Lambda Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) which is compiled at runtime into an Expression tree.  Even though the first solution looks the same at comile time, it is actually a delegate (i.e. "regular old compiled code).

Comment: ...However, if I understand @Smit correctly, he's also saying that when they see delegates inside Expression trees, they transform them into Expressions.

Comment: @mikebridge Your second snippet has no delegates.  It has an `Expression` that describes how one might go about creating a delegate, but it doesn't actually ever create one, ever.  In your first snippet you actually create a delegate.  ` if I understand @Smit correctly, he's also saying that when they see delegates inside Expression trees, they transform them into Expressions.`  It can't.  This will never work; hence the exception.  Once you have a delegate you've lost the data the ORM needs to translate it into SQL.

Comment: Sorry, I should have reversed the order of my sentence to make it clearer, but that's essentially what I'm saying.  As for @Smit, he is an [Entity Framework contributor](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/graphs/contributors) at Microsoft so I'm going to give him the benefit of the doubt. :)  I would assume they're reflecting the signature, but I don't know.

Comment: @mikebridge Smit has since said that the bug is that the code  throws, when it should instead simply behave incorrectly and not actually do what it's supposed to do (which ought to be to throw), basically hiding the problem and not letting you realize that your code isn't working.  The code can't translate the delegate into SQL; it's just impossible; the information it needs to do that has long since been lost.  The only sensible behavior is to throw.  Be glad that this "bug" caused you to actually realize your query isn't working and use this opportunity to fix it.